# Launching background threads in C with a single statement

Tags: c, multithreading, macros

I've read quite a bit about the Go language. There's a lot I didn't like about it - enough that I don't want to use it in day-to-day life. However, there is one bit about the language that I really do like: goroutines.

I was thinking of ways of implementing it in C. So far, the best I can find on the internet is

```
#define go if (!fork()) for(;;exit(0))
```

That way, you can prefix function calls with go, so that

```
go printf("Hello, world!\n");
```

runs in a different thread, as well as:

```
go { printf("Hello, world!\n"); foo(); bar(); baz(); }
```

But, of course, fork() has speed issues. (On my box, it takes 7 times as long to fork() as it is to printf(), benchmarked using the rdtsc x86 instruction and running a few times to eliminate the possibility of switching between cores or being scheduled out.)

So, my question is, is there a better way of implementing this, so that it's faster?

Comment: complaining that fork() is slower than printf() is like complaining that your elephant didn't come with a free F-18 fighter. They're not at all related.

Comment: This may be of some interest: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html.

Comment: "so that ... runs in a different thread" But fork() doesn't fire up a new thread - it fires up a new *process*.

Comment: That implementation is very, very broken. Try this: `printf("Hello, "); go printf(" world!\n"); exit(0);` and watch what happens.

Comment: Marc B - I prefer benchmarking calls in relation to printf() just as a common sort of benchmark. It's just something I do.

Adam Mihalcin - I'm usually fairly incoherent. What I meant is, in general, something which is executing separately from the thread of execution placing the call. I meant thread as in sort of an abstract "different point of execution" sort of way.

Comment: This implementation has nothing to do with how Go does goroutines.

Comment: @Fyzz_: It's not a very meaningful benchmark in most situations.  The performance of `printf` will be entirely dominated by a whole bunch of stuff that's highly variable and out of your control (system call, stream buffering, etc.).

Comment: Wow! `fork()` is only seven times slower than `printf()`!  That's amazingly fast.  I cut my teeth on VMS's `sys$creprc` which probably ran 1000 times as long as the equivalent of `printf()`.

Comment: Oli - I've found it to be very consistent, at around 100,000 clock cycles per call on average.

Comment: jdi - As in the concept of goroutines, not necessarily literally how they're implemented.

Comment: David Schwartz - is your point that printf() isn't thread-safe?

Comment: @Fyzz_: Then your questions title should really be something like "How to launch background threads in C with a single statement". Suggesting you want "Goroutines" implies you want the multiplexing of function calls onto threads, and the whole communication and scheduling functionality that comes with it.

Comment: jdi - Words and me don't really mix well. I wanted something that looks like launching goroutines. I renamed the question.

Comment: @Fyzz_: No. This code isn't multi-threaded. The problem is that you call `exit` from two streams of execution to flush the same stream, the one that was cloned when you call `fork`. Try it! You'll be very surprised with the output. The problem is that you clone `stdout` and can't decide which process owns the stream. So if the parent writes to it and then the child writes to it, you're in a disastrous bind. The output will be, most likely, `Hello, Hello,  world!`.

Answer (score 1):

Goroutines are mostly a fancy word for threads, with some extra functionality for inter-thread communication and such.

I am guessing the part you are interested in is the ability to succintly run a section of code in a separate thread.  Unfortunately there isn't a simple way to do this in C - you would have to write a function that enclosed the code you wanted to run in a the background, and use a macro or function that accepted that function and did the necessary magic using `pthread_create()` or similar.

Unless someone comes up with a clever way to use macros to create a function on-the-fly?  Anyone?

Keep in mind that in all but the most basic threaded application you will need some sort of synchronization, which will make things much less simple.

Comment: I think you have oversimplified the definition of goroutines. They don't just launch threads.

Comment: @jdi makes a good point.  For one thing, this simplification completely misses Go's channels, which use communication rather than locks for synchronization.

Comment: I was more after the syntax for launching them. I like how simple it is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). It allows threads to be spawned for code blocks and loop iterations with relatively simple `#pragma` directives.  It has been around for over a decade, and is already available in many compilers (including `gcc`).

Starting work in a thread should be faster than `fork()`, but the performance improvement may be obscured by behind-the-scenes thread-pool initialization overhead in simple applications that don't manage many threads.